Remove top Faces still using curves, is it possible?
I have a logo in .svg format that I imported into Blender. I've extruded the text upwards. However, I would like to know if it's possible to remove the top face of the logo. Is this doable while working with Curves, or do I need to convert the Curves to a mesh?
The file:


Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

I don't understand. Do you want me to explain in more detail? :)

No need, just add a few screenshot images showing your model and your settings

You can change the Fill Mode option, choose Back if you want to remove the top faces:


Thanks!! This is what I wanted!
